# Event times set with moment.js are 1:30h forward than local when deploying to Netlify

Tags: node.js, momentjs, netlify

I have a node.js script that uses `moment.js` to create timetables. Locally (in Minsk) it works good, but when i deploy it to Netlify every event is 1:30 forward than local one.

How to fix it?

Comment: Consider working on UTC time all the time.
Then if you want it to work on your time, move the hours +- the GMT you live in.

Comment: How to make it UTC?

Comment: @Talg123 I made it UTC `moment.utc(date).utcOffset('+03:00')` but it didnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to implement moment is to write an `override.js` file.

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.setDefault('UTC');
```

and call it at the first line of the server.

You can find any example below which is how **Ghost CMS** has implemented the moment.js

- [override.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/8cf644d5ba2f5652c00e3e09c578e4bbf210f59e/core/server/overrides.js#L25)
- [index.js](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/8aac74b3e86181ec4a399f3964f18ddf936b8329/core/server/index.js#L13)